# Ubuntu 10.10 USB drive not showing

Tags: usb, usb-drive

USB  is detecting but not showing the drives or mount details.

Nothing there inside my /media folder and /mnt folder.

I already enabled automatic mount and give privilege to user also.

My `sudo fdisk -l` shows like:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d3ba7



Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       29637   238053376   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           29637       30402     6142977    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           29637       30402     6142976   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Any idea?

Comment: The question is too general. You should elaborate on the problem - explain exactly what happens when you do xyz.

Comment: are you sure that this is all that appears from `sudo fdisk -l`? try connecting the drive then type `sudo fdisk -l`, wait untill you see the "$" sign again. It may take more than 5 minutes. ... I also want you to do something else... open a terminal, type `ls /dev/ | grep sd` then connect the drive then wait about 10 seconds then type `ls /dev/ | grep sd` again and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check the contents of `/media`? Also start a terminal session and type in the following:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Then insert a USB key. In the output that is displayed you'll see a line like this hopefully:

```
Mar 26 11:43:45 dt-ca-its-linux01 kernel: [11512.782402]  sdb: sdb1
```

The `/media` directory now also shows this:

```
user@linux01:/media$ ls
```

`5F07-50A5` <- This is the USB key.

Let us know if any of this shows up and then we'll work on the issues from there.

Comment: Similar issue (I bailed after create usb startup disk messed up but it was working before) This is the syslog: http://pastebin.com/7xn2j7fg any clue?